# DataRowExtensions.SetField vs индексатор

Tags: c#, ado.net

Есть ли какая-то разница между присваиванием нового значение `DataRow` через `DataRowExtensions.SetField` и через индексатор по имени?

Comment: декомпилируйте и поглядите :)

Answer (score 1):

Глянул [исходники](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.DataSetExtensions/System/Data/DataRowExtensions.cs) и похоже, что тоже самое, что и обращение через индексатор:

```
 public static void SetField<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName, T value) {
        DataSetUtil.CheckArgumentNull(row, "row");
        row[columnName] = (object)value ?? DBNull.Value;
    }
```

С той лишь разницей, что Null заменяется на DbNull. Однако, в чем в этом профит? На сколько я помню, ничего не препятствует присвоить обычный Null.

Comment: Сначала думали, что `null` в каких-то случаях может быть вполне корректным непустым значением колонки объектного типа, и навсегда зафиксировали это в индексаторе. Потом передумали, и появилось расширение SetField :-)

Comment: Т.е правильно присваивать все таки DbNull, а не Null, где не значений?

Comment: При использовании индексатора - да, правильно присваивать DbNull. Попытка присвоить null может и вовсе привести к исключению если это не объектная колонка.